# NetApp 7-Mode simulator CIFS share creation

Tags: cifs, netapp

What are the different ways to create CIFS share on NetApp 7-mode simulator? I created share using command line argument and NetApp onCommand System Manager. I want to know is  there any other way to do the same things?

Answer (score 0):

Well, everything will create basically the same way.  System Manger is using the API, you can code yourself some scripts or apps to use the API, or you can use Workflow Automation(WFA) to do this work, but again, this is just calling the API.  Once the 7-mode shares are setup, they can be managed with the windows mmc though.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding 7 Mode Systems:

It is always better to work with CLI. Just one example:

If you create a volume on 7 mode systems you have no chance to define the security style. You have to change it after the volume is created. That will be often forgotten.

I only work with CLI.